# Combat Efficiency Ribbon Streak Bonus

Tags: battlefield-3

What constitutes a Streak Bonus? This is in relation to obtaining the Combat Efficiency Ribbon, which states that you have to obtain 3 Streak Bonuses in a round.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wording on the bonus is really silly (same goes for the Nemesis ribbon). Once you get 5 kills, you're considered to be a on Combat Efficiency streak. Your 6th kill gives you a 1 streak bonus, 7th kill gives you 2 streak bonus and 8th gives you a 3 streak bonus and hence the ribbon.

It is possible to get multiple ribbons in the one life. Once you have got the first one, (I think) you will get the next one for every 3 subsequent kills in that life.

So if you go on a 23 kill streak you are going to 6 get of these ribbons (8 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3)

Comment: thanks for the clarification. i was always wondering how to get that ribbon.

Answer (score 5):

Combat Efficiency Ribbon 
500 XP Bonus. Get 3 Kill Streaks in one round. To get a streak, you need to kill 8 times in a row without dying yourself. Get 3 Kill Streaks of 8 to unlock this ribbon, try playing on infantry heavy maps to increase your chances early on.

Per http://www.gamefront.com/battlefield-3-ribbons-guide/

Comment: That can't be right. I only say that because I just got a ribbon, but only 18 kills. It could be 5 or 6 kills in a row. It should be noted that i'm referring to PC, but I can't see why it would be different for the consoles.

Comment: Well it was 7 kills on BC2, so I think it's the same here.

Comment: Turns out that this is right, but the wording on the bonus is really silly. Once you get 5 kills, you're considered to be a on Combat Efficiency streak. Your 6th kill gives you a 1 streak bonus, 7th kill gives you 2 streak bonus and 8th gives you a 3 streak bonus and hence the ribbon...

Comment: @Albort: If that's true, make it an answer with a reference, because that is not what this answer is saying.

Answer (score 1):

After 5 kills without dying, every 3rd thereafter is considered to extend the 'streak'.

Thus, to get three in a row, it would be 14 kills. (5 +3 +3 +3 = 14)